# Where is the source for DotNetOpenAuth? The primary Sourceforge link contains just samples and the ApplicationBlock

Tags: c#, oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

Now that DNOA may do [Call Home Reporting](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/openid/dotnetopenauth%e2%80%99s-%e2%80%9ccall-home%e2%80%9d-reporting/) I want to investigate the source to see exactly what is being transmitted to the DNOA servers.

The link on [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/) only gives me the "Application Block" some samples, and a compiled DLL.

Where is the source?  Am I just overlooking it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [DotNetOpenAuth home page](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) has a link directly to the source code.  You can download it by clicking the Download button once you're there.

Since you've expressed interested in downloading the source code for your specific version, once you're on the [source download page](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/downloads), look under **download tags** for your version and click that.

You also expressed concern about what is being reported.  I'm glad you're conscientious about this.  I'm sorry that the link that describes reporting seems to be broken (it's only showing the first few lines of the post for me).  Here is [a link that shows the entire post that explains reporting pretty well](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2010/01/dotnetopenauths-call-home-reporting.html).  If you're concerned about anything you find, you can turn off part or all of reporting in its entirety.  The steps to do that are near the top of the post.

Lastly, responding to your concern about so many downloads that omit the source or are scattered on several sites.  Most users seem to be interested in the binary, samples, and documentation.  The source is fairly large and so while it's freely available it's not included in the promoted downloads.  I agree, DotNetOpenAuth's content is fairly scattered across several sites.  The poor (literally) reason for that is simply that no site provides *everything* that DotNetOpenAuth needs among its free services, and DotNetOpenAuth is largely an unfunded project, so it spreads its requirements across those sites willing to make those services available for free.

Comment: Thanks for the updated links.  I'll admit I did see the project "dotnetopenid project", but wasn't entirely sure that was the right source for `DotNetOpenAuth.dll`.  There are so many different people who make OpenID DLL's...  Once I saw you were the same author, the dates and version numbers lined up, then I started the process of downloading the source.  The time spent sorting through the links is worth it, you build great stuff even if I had to debug all the URL's to get to it ;).  Regarding the the project, I do intend to donate once I turn a profit.

Answer (score 1):

The source for DNOA isn't on Sourceforge - it's on [github](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/).

Comment: ...confusing it is.  The main website http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ says the link is on Sourceforge.  How would someone know that? geez

Comment: @makerofthings: On the DNOA page, the "Get the latest stable source" link on the right hand side goes straight to the github page.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to references https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid

After having a quick look inside, I found some of what you might be looking for in:

https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/v3.4/src/DotNetOpenAuth/Reporting.cs

Comment: I'm looking for the 3.4.6.10357 source.  I guess I didn't click the tiny link since I don't want the latest oAuth 2.0 code, just the 1.0 stuff from late 2010.  Why publish the same thing in several different locations with different names? It's confusting.

Comment: Would appreciate any help you can offer in downloading that source.  I don't see it in the 7z file.  That marks the 10th download I've done tonight to find the source.

Comment: On the github download page https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/archives/v3.4 you should see a button that says "Download Zip" pointing to https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/zipball/v3.4 . The source is in there.

Comment: Thanks! I just went though the pains of using Git to get it.  Many of the downloads I grabbed omitted that SRC directory.  Thanks!