# How do I update a Strongly-Named DLL within an ASP.NET website to use a newer version of delay signed DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth, strongname

In debugging the [LinkedInToolkit](http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/), I downloaded the [DotNetOpenAuth source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929269/where-is-the-source-for-dotnetopenauth-the-primary-sourceforge-link-contains-jus) from git.  Now that I've added the reference I'm getting the following error when compiling the prebuilt websites the come from LinkedInToolkit

> Could not load file or assembly
>   DotNetOpenAuth version 3.4.7.11039. 
>   Strong name signature could not be
>   modified....

Considering that the DotNetOpenAuth DLL is delay signed, how to I make my website compile and run?

I've searched web.config and references for any mention of a strongly named DLL.  Where else would the strong name check be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you're compiling DotNetOpenAuth yourself, you should either turn off delay signing completely, or change the key it is signed with to one that you have the private key to.  Don't disable strong name checking -- that's a security risk.

Curious why you have to compile your own DotNetOpenAuth library though.

Comment: I read through the OAuth specs and want to take this time to learn more about the implementation protocol, not to mention the core security feature of my application. I just want to be duly informed, if asked about its' operation. Aside from the fun factor, I just cant hit F5 and run the LinkedInToolkit and run the sample with the latest DotNetOpenOauth DLL when added as a reference. I'm on a learning detour now with all this delay signed stuff. Question: How do I turn on delay signing, just uncheck project properties?

Comment: Also, @Andrew For what it's worth, I get the compilation error only when I build the site. Not when I build DNOA.DLL or the LinkedInDLL

Comment: If you build DNOA from a command-line with elevated privileges, the dll will automatically be registered for skip-verification.  That may be your easiest approach.  If you then go to production, you'll need to either use the official distribution or change/remove the signing key.

Answer (score 0):

You should also search in the references of your project references and so on until you find a DLL which depends on a signed version of the `DotNetOpenAuth` assembly. Note that this assembly could be dynamically loaded and might not even appear in the list of referenced assemblies. You could also [disable strong name checking temporary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713694.aspx) but make sure you realize the possible consequences of this.

Comment: These are "Web Sites" not Web Projects... references seem to be handled differently and in a way I'm unfamiliar with.  I did delete the BIN and OBJ folders...